# Creating a rule in postgresql to automatically add a json on INSERT

Tags: postgresql

I'm creating a discord member db in PostgreSQL but I'm still a beginner.
And I'm trying, as specified in the title, to create a rule that, when I add a new member to the db, adds a json to that member's column.
Here's the code I got so far and it's not working:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE tank_json AS
ON INSERT TO public.members
DO (UPDATE members
    SET tank={"own_tank"=0, "engine"=0, "wheels"=0, "cannon"=0}
    WHERE NEW.name);
```

I think that the problem might be on the last part "WHERE NEW.name" but I'm not sure how else I'm supposed to specify where it should add that json without messing with the other member's data.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Advice: Forget the existence of RULE's. Second, this looks like a default value for a field, so why don't you use a default for that column? No need for complexity at all. As of version 13 you could also use a generated column: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html

Comment: Hmmm yeah for this especially maybe I don't need something so complex like making a rule. As I said I'm still a beginner, I didn't even know that that was possible. Thanks alot for the advice :)